# New Database Architecture with Access

Tags: database, ms-access-2010, metadata

I'm new to building databases, took an MBA course on DB design but have little prior experience. I work at a company that does construction; we have jobs, customers, vendors, employees, and machines.  I am trying to pull this together into a coherent Access database. Below is a relationship diagram for what I've built so far. Am I creating too many tables and making it more complicated than it needs to be?

Also, should I be 100% sure on the data I should be collecting before I start adding information, or is it reasonable to be able to tweak tables and add in new ones if needed on the backend?

[image: Relationship Diagram]

Comment: It is reasonable to be able to tweak tables and add new ones if needed on the backend.  Your database diagram looks reasonable to me, but what matters is that your database works for your company.

Comment: I don't recognize that ER diagramming tool. But it's not indicating the types of relationships, such as one-to-many, many-to-many, etc. Most tools give you the ability to do that, which makes automated database generation much nicer.